# How can I control which Safari window hyperlinks open in?

Tags: safari, links

I'm not sure I worded my question correctly, but I wasn't sure how else to ask it.

I have multiple Safari windows open. In apps besides Safari, if I click on a link, it opens the link in one of the windows (the window that was opened first). This isn't always what I want. It appears that that first window is viewed as my primary window (or something similar). Is there a way I can set the 'primary window' to be one of my other Safari windows (without having to close and reopen all windows in a certain order)?